# Elementary counting techniques

Tags: combinatorics

Pizza making: meat toppings are( sausage, pepperoni and hamburger). Veggies are ( mushrooms, peppers, onions and olives).

A- How many different pizzas contain at most one meat topping?

B- How many different pizzas contain no meat?

Well I get the idea for B, which I got 48. But for the part A I don't really get it i know it's saying at most which means one or non.

Comment: What makes you think the answer for $B$ is $48$?  That is not the answer I'm getting.  Presumably there is no limit to the number of toppings used and it doesn't matter in what order the toppings are placed onto the pizza.  further assume that there are no options for "extra pepperoni" etc... i.e. either the pizza contains topping $x$ or it doesn't contain topping $x$.  Apply multiplication principle with the step "pick whether the pizza contains topping $x$" for each topping individually.

Comment: For the meatless pizza, this involves only asking the questions "does it contain mushrooms?  does it contain peppers? does it contain onions?  does it contain olives?"  Each individual question having two options, yes or no.  Applying multiplication principle that should be $2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2=16$ options, not $48$.  For the pizzas containing at most one meat, decide whether the pizza has no meat, sausage, pepperoni, or hamburger and then decide which if any vegetables are used.  Again applying multiplication principle should yield an answer.

Comment: Your right. This is what I was doing exactly but I changed it because I saw some online explanation and changed my mind. And for A that would be 48 not B, I'm sorry your right.because u got 3 choices for meat toppings and 16 for the veggies 3*16=48

Comment: $48=3\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2$ is the correct number of pizzas containing *exactly one meat topping* and doesn't count the number of pizzas with no meat topping.  Instead of $3$ options for the number of ways of having at most one meat choice, it is instead $4$ since the option of "none" is included.  Alternatively worded, it is $3\cdot 2^4 + 1\cdot 2^4$, the number of pizzas with one meat topping plus the number of pizzas with no meat toppings

Comment: Genius you are. Great thinking, problem solved

Comment: As an aside, if the number of toppings in the example increases, it will become easier to describe the results using [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).  E.g. if there are $15$ meats available and $20$ vegetables available, the number of pizzas with exactly three meats chosen and no limit on vegetables will be $\binom{15}{3}\cdot 2^{20}$

Comment: Yep. Great example u got there.